# What anime is this guy from? He has brown hair and is wearing a school uniform

Tags: guilty-crown

i tried different sites, so now I'm here. If anyone could help that would be great. If you could, can you tell me which anime he is from and the name of the character. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as apart of the phase out of image only id requests. [Meta for further reading](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2736/1587)

Answer (score 11):

This is for sure the Anime **Guilty Crown** (ギルティクラウン). There is also a Manga of this Anime. [Icyk](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/8319/icyk) already answered correct but his answer is low quality. I searched the other things up.

### Information

[image: Cover]

- Type: TV
- Episodes: 22
- Status: Finished Airing
- Aired: Oct 14, 2011 to Mar 23, 2012
- Producers: Production I.G, Aniplex, FUNimation EntertainmentL, Movic, Fuji TV, Fuji Pacific Music Publishing
- Genres: Action, Drama, Sci-Fi, Super Power
- Duration: 24 min. per episode
- Rating: R - 17+ (violence & profanity)

> The story takes place in Tokyo in 2039, after the outbreak of the
>   "Apocalypse Virus" during what became known as the "Lost Christmas" of
>   2029. Since then, Japan has been under the control of the multinational organization called GHQ.
>
> Ouma Shu is a 17 year-old boy who mistakenly obtains a rare and great
>   power. He can use this power, "The Right Hand of the King," to extract
>   "voids," or tools/weapons that are the manifestations of peoples'
>   hearts.
>
> He has been rather shy since a childhood tragedy, but both his
>   personality and life change forever when he meets a girl named
>   Yuzuriha Inori, a member of the rebel group called "Funeral Parlor,"
>   whose members seek the restoration of self-government in Japan via the
>   ousting of GHQ.

<sub>from [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/10793/Guilty_Crown)</sub>

### Character

The character you see in the picture is *Shu Ouma* (桜満 集). He is the main character of the Anime. At the beginning you can say he is introverted and just a normal high school student.

[image: Shu Ouma]

<sub>from [ZeroChan](http://www.zerochan.net/1201358)</sub>

> One of the main protagonists of Guilty Crown, who's right hand holds a
>   special power called "The Power of the King". This ability allows him
>   to extract weapons from his friends known as a "Void" which is a
>   manifestation of a person's personality.
>
> He is an unsociable 17-year-old young man who usually tends to stay
>   out of people's way so as to not cause them any trouble. However, this
>   changes when he meets a girl named Inori Yuzuriha. From that moment
>   on, he must learn how to make friends because of his ability "The
>   Power of King".

<sub>from [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/character/43278/Shu_Ouma)</sub>

### Scene

The scene in your picture is in the opening of the Anime. It starts at 1:09 in this [YouTube](http://youtu.be/DjUtmbZt8zc?t=1m9s) video.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like [Shu Ouma](http://guiltycrown.wikia.com/wiki/Shu_Ouma), the main character of [Guilty Crown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilty_Crown) ;) If you watch [the opening](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjUtmbZt8zc), you can see that the visual style is similar to your picture.

Here's another picture of him:

[image: Shu Ouma]

I really like this anime :)

Answer (score 3):

The character you're looking at is [Shu Ouma](http://myanimelist.net/character/43278/Shu_Ouma) - the main protagonist from [Guilty Crown](http://myanimelist.net/anime/10793/Guilty_Crown), and that specific scene is from the opening.

Guilty Crown is quite a popular anime, however according to [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/), more popular than it is good (as seen by the rankings - Ranked #616, Popularity Ranked #38).

> The story takes place in Tokyo in 2039, after the outbreak of the "Apocalypse Virus" during what became known as the "Lost Christmas" of 2029. Since then, Japan has been under the control of the multinational organization called GHQ. 
>    - [Source](http://myanimelist.net/anime/10793/Guilty_Crown)

Though, on the same page detailing more into the character -

(Episode 1 spoiler - mouse-hover to view)

> Ouma Shu is a 17 year-old boy who mistakenly obtains a rare and great power. He can use this power, "The Right Hand of the King," to extract "voids," or tools/weapons that are the manifestations of peoples' hearts.

I won't go throwing more information at you - I'd rather recommend watching the first episode - **it's the best way for you to see if you like it or not**!